# How to properly get list of remotes files before the pull

Tags: git

I've see that I can get a list of files that will be pulled down by running the following commands (scripted):

```
branch_name=`git branch | grep ^\* | awk '{print $2}'`
git fetch
git diff --stat  origin/${branch_name}
```

This works fine. However, if I choose not to do the merge (or pull), and try again to check, I might not get any results (e.g. if I try too soon to check). Is there a way to clear the fetch and run this as a clean check every time?

Answer (score 1):

Like that :

```
branch_name=`git branch | grep ^\* | awk '{print $2}'`
old_commit=$(git rev-parse origin/${branch_name})
git fetch
git diff --stat origin/${branch_name}
git update-ref refs/remotes/origin/${branch_name} $old_commit
```

Should do the magic trick.
It will "just" print the file changes in the upstream, and hopefully leave your repository completly unchanged.